# How to plot last Open or Close on current candle as a Circle by checking candle[1] for signal

Tags: pine-script

I have been working on an algorithm for pinescript and I am stuck with some logic relating to hypothetically entering the position.

First of all **bullPlot and bearPlot** are either **true or false** which is where the **long and short** signals are painted on the chart. Relating to my strategy, once a long/short signal is plotted you then wait for price to go beyond **the close for long/short depending on red/green candle**

How can I create a statement which checks if there is a signal on the previous candle, if true, plot a circle based on last close. This is merely to help with the manual trading side of the algorithm.

[example of the chart/algo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdFQ4.png)

[example of entry dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cuyt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a series that holds your trigger result on each bar.
Then you can just reference the trigger value on the previous bar by using the `[1]` construct, and plot `close[1]` on the current bar.

When you don't want a value in a series plotted, you can make it plot the `na` value, like this:

```
signal_on_previous_candle ? previousClose : na
```

The `?:` is a [ternary operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#conditional-operator-and-the-iff-function), which is a shortend `if-then-else` statement.
The above code can also be written as

```
if signal_on_previous_candle
    previousClose
else
    na
```

I think this what you're looking for

```
//@version=4
study("bullPlot", overlay=true)

var bool signal_on_candle = false
signal_trigger_time = timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), 11, 30, 0)

signal_triggered = time == signal_trigger_time

if signal_triggered
    signal_on_candle := true
else
    signal_on_candle := false

signal_on_previous_candle = signal_on_candle[1]

previousClose = close[1]

plot(signal_on_previous_candle ? previousClose : na, title="Dot",style=plot.style_circles, color=color.yellow, linewidth=5)
```

This code could be shorter, but it's for illustration purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! This explanation helped a ton!

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)